# Difference between using azure webjobs and Hangfre background job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, hangfire

I did a lot of search about jobs and found that there is azure webjobs and hangfire jobs that can excute jobs in a time schedule so what is the difference between these two types ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hangfire performs background processing in .NET and .NET Core applications. Azure WebJobs provide an easy way to run scripts or programs (such as cmd, bat, exe (.NET), ps1, sh, php, py, js and jar) as background processes, and WebJobs SDK could work with C# script, Node.js, and other languages. Besides, WebJobs has a binding and trigger system, which enables us to easily work with Azure Storage and Service Bus.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :)

Comment: Also, if you want to run jobs outside of your IIS w3wp process you would use a continuous Azure WebJob to run the Hangfire background worker.

Comment: I found this article to be useful. It favors hangfire because it allows jobs to be delayed and retried. Also the job dashboarding is way better compared to azure: [link](https://rimdev.io/considering-hangfire-in-windows-azure-instead-of-webjobs/)